# SSO login to shared account

Tags: single-sign-on

sso enabled in org and everything works fine. we have new requirement like 2 different users want to login with same account I mean user x and user y wants to login salesforce with same user called xy user in salesforce through sso. is it possible? do we have any solution or workaround for this. Thank you so much in advance for your help.

Comment: Each person must have their own user ID.  https://help.salesforce.com/s/articleView?id=000382039&type=1  Sharing user credentials violates the terms&conditions of your agreement.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There's lots of reasons why this can't work

### Reason One - The Way SSO works

- The Identity Provider's job is to authenticate a single user with MFA to a single user
- When the user requests access to a Salesforce resource (clicking a link in an email for example), SFDC makes a request to the IdP.
- The IdP authenticates the user and in a SAML assertion, passes the user's identity back to SFDC.
- SFDC matches the user's identity to either the SFDC UserName or Federation Id (depending on how you configured SFDC Single Signon). Those values are unique

### Reason Two - Each user should have their own SFDC user seat

- SFDC MFA rules require this; no sharing of seats
- SFDC master services agreement requires this